# Excel VBA populate listbox with data from sheet using only rows that match variable

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm building an Excel program at work so that collegues can view their upsells. What i'm stuck on is the population of the listbox.
When I populate the listbox it returns all rows. What I need it too return though is all rows where the name in the E column matches with the one contained in the public variable.
I searched all over to try and find a solution but have not had any luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is starting to bug me now.

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
   var_associate = "Kirsty" 
   Dim var_nextline As Integer 
   var_nextline = 1 
   x = "a" 
   Do While x <> "" 
      x = Cells(var_nextline, 2) 
      If x <> var_associate Then 
          var_nextline = var_nextline + 1 
      Else 
          Me.lsb_upsell.AddItem(var_nextline, 2).Value 
          var_nextline = var_nextline + 1 
      End If 
   Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: Below is the code I have so far:

Comment: Public Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
var_associate = "Kirsty" 
Dim var_nextline As Integer 

var_nextline = 1 

x = "a" 

Do While x <> "" 

x = Cells(var_nextline, 2) 
If x <> var_associate Then var_nextline = var_nextline + 1 
Else 
Me.lsb_upsell.AddItem(var_nextline, 2).Value 
var_nextline = var_nextline + 1 
Loop 
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Cells(var_nextline, 2)
```

should give an error, as the right-hand side returns the cell object, not the value contained in the cell, and assignment of objects must be done by using `Set`. Anyway, it is not what you want to have. Try

```
x = Cells(var_nextline, 2).Value2
```

Remark: You could improve your code:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   Dim var_associate As String
   var_associate = "Kirsty" 

   Dim var_nextline As Integer
   var_nextline = 1

   Dim x As String
   Do
      x = Cells(var_nextline, 2).Value2
      If x = "" Then Exit Loop
      If x = var_associate Then
         Me.lsb_upsell.AddItem(x).Value
      End If
      var_nextline = var_nextline + 1
   Loop

End Sub
```

Second remark: Where is `Cells` initialized (e.g. with `Set Cells = ActiveSheet.Cells`)? Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your file in order to get error messages for undeclared variables. Do you mean something like

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(var_nextline, 2).Value
```

?

Comment: `x = Cells(var_nextline, 2)` won't give an error ! .. have you tried it ? .. it will give you same as cell value ..

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the code JohnB. I did manage to get it too work as follows: Public Sub UserForm_Initialize() var_associate = "Kirsty" Dim var_nextline As Integer var_nextline = 2 x = "a" Do While x <> "" x = Worksheets("test").Cells(var_nextline, 1) If x <> var_associate Then var_nextline = var_nextline + 1 Else Me.lsb_upsell.AddItem Cells(var_nextline, 5).Value var_nextline = var_nextline + 1 End If Loop End Sub

I like your way better as it is more tidy.

Many Thanks